# Java: package access from different jars

Tags: java, jar, jboss

Why do I get "java.lang.IllegalAccessError" at runtime when both the classes with package access are in the same package but in different jars?

This is a legacy application running in Jboss 4.x and Java 1.7. I had to repackage the classes into two separate jars due to refactoring.

Comment: Do you get it in compilation or runtime?

Comment: @MarounMaroun It is thrown at runtime.